# ¿Como borrar una fila de una tabla en base de datos con laravel?

Tags: php, sql, laravel, phpmyadmin, delete

Estoy en un proyecto con laravel donde cada vez que suben un inventario(archivo .csv) en la base de datos se llena una tabla "products". El problema es que toma la cabezera del archivo y lo llena como una fila de producto.

Para eliminar esa fila intente varios metodos, por ejemplo:

```
DB::table('products')->where('products_model', '=', 'PRODUCTO')->delete();
```

Pero me elimino toda la tabla "products"
¿Como puedo eliminar solamente esta fila con laravel?

Comment: Si te eliminó todos los registros es por que la condición del where se cumple para todos los renglones

Comment: "pruducts_model" es una columna y solo existe un registro con el nombre PRODUCTO

Comment: Tu problema no es ese. Tu problema debería ser que se esta subiendo informaicon incorrecta. Es una carga adicional imnecesaria al servidor y una muy mala practica. Ataca el problema real. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes intentar solo asi,

```
DB::table('products')->where('products_model','PRODUCTO')->delete();
```

Pero puede existir problema de que existan mas registros donde 'products_model' tenga el valor 'PRODUCTO', y te elimine mas de uno, por eso siempre se debe ser especifico el eliminar un dato en especifico

```
DB::table('products')->where([
['products_model','PRODUCTO'],
['id',$id]
])->delete();
```